# Date range query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, date-range

I want to fetch records from elasticsearch within a specific date range.
I have tried the following query-

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/150/_search?pretty" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"query\":{\"range\":{\"timestamp\":{\"gte\":\"16/Jan/2019\",\"lte\":\"18/Jan/2019\",\"boost\":2.0}}}}"
```

But here I am getting all the documents. Can anyone please help me to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following date format: `yyyy-MM-dd`. Try this instead:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/150/_search?pretty" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"query\":{\"range\":{\"timestamp\":{\"gte\":\"2019-01-16\",\"lte\":\"2019-01-18\",\"boost\":2.0}}}}"
```